# His angel (Rev. 1:1)

Tags: angel-of-the-lord, abyss

Is "a star out of heaven having fallen onto the earth. And was given to it the key to the pit of the of the abyss, and he opened the pit..." (Rev. 9:1, 2) His angel?

Rational: Rev. 1:18 "... And I have the **keys to Hades**, and of death."

Ref: The Interlinear Bible Hebrew, Greek, English, Strong's numbers; p951, 956

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that Jesus Christ sends His angel with His Hades key to open the abyss. This event allows the Beast to come up out of the abyss to kill the two witnesses after they "complete their witness" (Rev. 11:7)(day 1261).

Answer (score 0):

Consider these other references to stars, including a special star, the morning star, to provide context for your question:

> And you took up the tent of Molech, and **the star of your God**,
> Raiphan—the impressions of them which you made for yourselves. – Amos
> 5:25 LXX (APB), Acts 7:43 ESV

> “How you are fallen from heaven, O **Day Star, son of Dawn**! How you are
> cut down to the ground, you who laid the nations low! You said in your
> heart, ‘I will ascend to heaven above the stars of God. I will set my
> throne on high. I will sit on the mount of assembly in the far reaches
> of the north . . .’” - Isaiah 20:12,13 ESV

> And we have the prophetic word more fully confirmed, to which you will
> do well to pay attention as to a lamp shining in a dark place, until
> the day dawns and the **morning star** rises in your hearts, - 2 Peter
> 1:19 ESV

> The one who conquers and who keeps my works until the end, to him I
> will give authority over the nations, and he will rule them with a
> rod of iron, as when earthen pots are broken in pieces, even as I
> myself have received authority from my Father. And I will give him the
> **morning star**. - Revelation 2:26-28 ESV

> “I, Jesus, have sent my angel to testify to you about these things for
> the churches. I am the root and the descendant of David, the bright
> **morning star**.” - Revelation 22:16 ESV

So, from antiquity, stars were associated with gods and angels. The morning star has a special place of honor. The Apostle Paul explains it this way:

> There are heavenly bodies and earthly bodies, but the glory of the
> heavenly is of one kind, and the glory of the earthly is of another.
> There is one glory of the sun, and another glory of the moon, and
> another glory of the stars; for star differs from star in glory. So is
> it with the resurrection of the dead. What is sown is perishable; what
> is raised is imperishable. 1 Corinthians 15:40-42 ESV

Also consider the this star *fallen from heaven to earth* being given the key to the bottomless pit (a black hole is literally a bottomless pit) compared to Jesus:

When I saw him, I fell at his feet as though dead. But he laid his right hand on me, saying, “Fear not, I am the first and the last, and the living one. I died, and behold I am alive forevermore, and I have the keys of Death and Hades. - Revelation 1:17,18 ESV

These sound like different keys to different places. Revelation also makes a distinction between Death and Hades, the bottomless pit, and the lake of fire.

> Then Death and Hades were thrown into the lake of fire. This is the
> second death, the lake of fire. - Revelation 20:14 ESV

Understanding these terms and how they're used provide us a much better chance of understanding what's going to happen and where.